# Get All Facebook friends list in the new facebook graph api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

The official Facebook Graph API from facebook can give only friends which are also using the same app, but i found an app in Google Play Store that can get friends list without permission from facebook app, just after login get friends!

Any idea about how i can do it?

Comment: doesnt facebook have a {id}/friendslist api? the ID would be yours (or whoever)

Comment: not possible. but what app would that be? please be more specific on stackoverflow. always add as many details as possible.

Answer (score 2):

> but i found an app in Google Play Store that can get friends list without permission from facebook app, just after login get friends!

Then this app must most likely be scraping that data directly from the user’s profile - which is not allowed.

There is no way for normal 3rd-party apps to get access to all friends of a user using any of the official APIs.

> Any idea about how i can do it?

Why would you want to in the first place? As a user being aware of the limitations Facebook has placed upon this, I would immediately categorize your app as shady, and warn everyone I know about it …